# Can we combine Tableau Extract and live data?

Tags: amazon-redshift, reporting, tableau-api

I have a billing data set that ranges from 2017 to 2019 (until current). Data doesn't change for 2017,2018 and till November, 2019. It changes either for the current month or for the complete ongoing month..

I want to create one *.hyper* extract and store the static data in local server for the data that doesn't change and if needed also publish it for other users to use.

How to append the new data to extract? Can we union it with a live connection or append the data to the extract?

Comment: have you tried incremental refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on datasource compatibility, you can do this with `Tableau Prep` or the new `Hyper API`. Links as of 12/2019 are below.

[Tableau Prep](https://www.tableau.com/products/prep)

[Hyper API (Python)](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/hyper_api/en-us/reference/py/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a twbx (tableau packaged workbook) file on your local system open that and change the data source connection to live and click update.
Then publish this dashboard with the "same name" which has the latest data, tableau server will ask you if you want to replace the existing dashboard -> click yes

Not sure if you're using a database. If yes, you can create views and then connect them

1.live to tableau dashboard which will get you the latest data all the time

2.Extract mode to refresh based on a set frequency

Hope this helps!